# Preprocess multiple files into single file

Tags: boost, boost-preprocessor

I'm trying to simplify a distribution and build process that uses `boost::shared_ptr` (Android and STLport does not include `shared_ptr`). I used Boost's `bcp` to copy out `shared_ptr` and its dependencies. That resulted in 340 dependencies spread across numerous directories:

```
$ mkdir boost-shared_ptr
$ cd boost-1.54.0
$ ./dist/bin/bcp shared_ptr ../boost-shared_ptr
...
$ cd ../boost-shared_ptr
$ find . -type f | wc -l
340
```

Is there a way to pre-process `boost::shared_ptr` into a single file, and then place that single file (`shared_ptr.hpp`) into my `deps/` directory?

Answer (score 1):

This is bad idea. Numerous cons with very little pros. Always use boost files "as-is". In the majority of cases they are carefully engineered.

I can bet your users will benefit if you will give them your library that include original boost files. They will be able to download it themselves and/or upgrade the version.

Comment: Forgot... Thanks Kirill.